# Call onClick fun in onCreate fun and crashed app [Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api, onclick

get latitude and longitude when clicked on a `Button` and the result is shown on some `TextView`

in `onCreate` fun code :

```
    icon_id.setOnClickListener(this)
    buildGoogleApiClient()
```

but now I want to show lat-long when the app is started without clicking on any `Button`

so I deleted `.setOnClickListener` and call `onClick` directly but the app crashed.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
MainActivity.getLocation(MainActivity.kt:71)
 

    private fun getLocation() {
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)

        if (mLocation == null) {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            lat = mLocation!!.latitude
            lon = mLocation!!.longitude
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "location disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    

MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.kt:56)

    getLocation()

MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:103)

    var view = findViewById<View>(R.id.constraintLayout_id)
    onClick(view)
```

Comment: Please paste error log.

Comment: Please share crash logs from your logcat

Comment: make sure "icon_id" is not null and for more clarification share your error logcat and code

Comment: I guess there is a time-consuming operation in buildGoogleApiClient fun, which ended before you click on button, but have no time to complete if you call onClick directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to call the onClick method without setOnclickListeners,  paste error log would help a lot to find out what's really happened.

Check my code, it works well on my phone.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    buildGoogleApiClient()
    checkGps() }

private fun checkGps() {
    if (!checkGPSEnabled()) {
        return
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            getLocation();
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission()
        }
    } else {
        getLocation();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this code when call getLocation() get same error , more accurate error in line 2 of getLocation fun : mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the code inside `onClick()` into a separate funtion and call that from both `onClick()` and `onCreate()`

And make sure you call the function after setting up your `GoogleApiClient`

Comment: more accurate : i call onclick into seprate fun and call this fun in onCreate still same errors

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you want to show the Latitude and Longitude as soon as they are available in the app instead of having to click the button right?

Well, you are searching for something different. You're searching for a listener inside of the elements of your app. Or at least that can be a solution.

Actually your code is pretty close from what you want, you only have to move the calls from you `onClick` method outside of it and do it maybe `onStart` or create a method to do the actual calls.

Comment: You got to know exactly what I want, but i don't any solution, i wish there was OnStartListener and i use it inside OnClickListener :(